# Wordpress error establishing a database connection - Memory Issue

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have been running this wordpress site for a long time with no issues, however have recently been getting the error "Error establishing a database connection". If I restart mySQL the problem is temporarily fixed but will soon comes back.

After looking through the MySQL log files I believe the problem is because of some sort of memory leak, however I am having trouble tracking down the root of the problem.

I have read that the problem could be coming from a swapfile not being configured, however I have configured the swap as follows:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           987        968         18         26         18        137
-/+ buffers/cache:        812        175
Swap:          255         35        220
```

It would be awesome if anyone could help me make sense of this log file.

MySQL Log File:

```
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'innodb' with soname 'ha_innodb.so'.
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [ERROR] Function 'federated' already exists
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'federated' with soname 'ha_federated.so'.
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [ERROR] Function 'blackhole' already exists
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'blackhole' with soname 'ha_blackhole.so'.
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [ERROR] Function 'archive' already exists
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'archive' with soname 'ha_archive.so'.
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Binlog end
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2016-03-17 06:48:45 3575 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'innodb' with soname 'ha_innodb.so'.
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [ERROR] Function 'federated' already exists
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'federated' with soname 'ha_federated.so'.
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [ERROR] Function 'blackhole' already exists
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'blackhole' with soname 'ha_blackhole.so'.
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [ERROR] Function 'archive' already exists
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'archive' with soname 'ha_archive.so'.
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: Can you paste some of what comes before 2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 ?

Comment: @obe did I add the section you were looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's problem with your server memory. From your `MySQL` Log File we can get that InnoDb plugin failed to start due to unable to `Initializing buffer pool`. So any tables with InnoDb storage cause errors.

Your workaround solution

> If I restart mySQL the problem is temporarily fixed but will soon comes back.

works because you get some free memory after restarting Mysql.

```
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2016-03-17 06:48:46 3606 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: I had assumed the error had something to do with this. Do you know of any ways I could track the problem further?

Comment: You can decrease buffer pool in mysql config file to 20M with this string `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 20M`. Maybe there will be enough memory to start with this buffer size

Comment: Or you can set a smaller value for MySQL's max_connections variable

Comment: try to follow instructions from http://askubuntu.com/questions/457923/why-did-installation-of-mysql-5-6-on-ubuntu-14-04-fail/457932#457932

Answer (score 0):

alexander.polomodov is on the right track, but I'm guessing the configuration you need to change is MaxRequestWorkers (or MaxClients on older Apache systems) in your MPM-Prefork configurations.

You can run a diagnostic on your apache configuration using Apache2Buddy. It'll calculate how many Apache Workers you can run given the amount of RAM you have and how big your application is:
`$ curl -L http://apache2buddy.pl/ | perl`

Just update the values to what Apache2 recommends (the configs were at `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf` on my system). After that, just restart Apache and you should be good to go.

If you're site isn't handling a lot of traffic, you could be getting hit by bots. Check your Apache access logs `$ cat /var/log/apache2/access.log`

I wrote an article on this situation if you want a deeper explanation, a method to stress test, or ideas on how to block some of the bot traffic: http://brunzino.github.io/blog/2016/05/21/solution-how-to-debug-intermittent-error-establishing-database-connection/